# PHP / Axios - correctly formatting email object to pass to PHP mailer

Tags: javascript, php, axios, phpmailer

On the PHP side, what is the correct syntax to get all the key=>value pairs from an axios object being posted to a simple PHP mailer?

My ojbect:

```
let post = {
  message: this.message, // string
  email: this.email, // string
  links: this.links // array of objects { name: item.name, id: item.id }
};
axios.post('/mail.php', JSON.stringify(post)).then(() => { ... });
```

In my mailer I'm doing this:

```
$_POST = json_decode(array_keys($_POST)[0], true);

if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $body = $_POST['message'];
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
if (isset($_POST['links'])) {
    $links = $_POST['links'];
}
```

But this doesn't get everything... I'm assuming because of the `[0]` but if I remove the [0] json_decode complains. (I'm not super excellent at PHP yet).

What I would **love** is for vars to be assigned like this:

```
$message = json_decode(array_keys($_POST)[0], true);
$email = json_decode(array_keys($_POST)[1], true);
$links = json_decode(array_keys($_POST)[2], true);
```

But that doesn't work either.

Comment: can't you just send it as normal post? i think that stringify adds more complexity, then just access the post keys as you normally would, i just read the docu https://github.com/axios/axios it doesn't need to be `stringified`, just send the object as is

Comment: and your expected assignment (the one that ideally you would want it to) won't be possible since the payload is sent as a whole json string, you can't reapply it individually. you use `json_decode`, then access the data

Answer (score 0):

I removed the stringify from the axios post and then in the PHP mailer I used:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}

if (isset($data['email'])) {
  $to = $data['email'];
}

if (isset($data['message'])) {
  $body = $data['message'];
}

if (isset($data['links'])) {
  $to = $data['links'];
}
```